# Magento 2.2 - Required parameter 'theme_dir' was not passed when uploading image upload

Tags: magento2

When I'm going to upload product image I see this error "R`equired parameter 'theme_dir'` was not passed".

I'm using a Theme.

Comment: From the error seems that you have a theme configured which doesn't exist on the file-system (anymore).